# partial page not rendering css class correctly

Tags: css, angularjs

I have created .css classes to create circles of different colors.  If I use the css class in one file it works as expected.  However when I try to use it in an angular partial page it does not render correctly?

correct:  [image: Correct]
incorrect: [image: Incorrect]

Here is css class for red circles

```
  .red-circle {
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c92c09;
}.red-circle:before, .red-circle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
}.red-circle:before {
  float: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  background: #c92c09;
}.red-circle:after {
  float: right;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background: #c92c09;
}
```

And here is how it is being used in the correct html page

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/circles.css" type="text/css" />
 <body>      
      <div class="red-circle"><div>
    </body>
```

and here is the html that displays incorrectly

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="FieldCtrl">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/circles.css" type="text/css" />
    <div class="red-circle"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear how to reproduce the error, though it is worth noting that the HTML for your "correct" version is actually invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `position`and `top` and remove `floats`, instead use `right`and `left`

**CSS**

```
.red-circle {
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c92c09;
  position: relative;
}

.red-circle:before,
.red-circle:after {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 30px;
}

.red-circle:before {
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  background: #c92c09;
}

.red-circle:after {
  right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background: #c92c09;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/wsa1fxcv/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I have spent over 4 hours and bang you solve it right away.